# iframe background image

Tags: html

I have a iframe on my page. I have inserted a background image on it. but its not showing the Image. Here is my code.

```
 <iframe scrolling="auto" allowtransparency="true" name="main" style="width:100%;height:90%" style="background-image:url(img/bg2.jpg)"> </iframe>
```

Comment: you are using to style attributes, try merging them into one

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
<iframe scrolling="auto" allowtransparency="true" name="main" style="width:100%;height:90%;background-image:url(img/bg2.jpg)"> </iframe>
```

if it doesn't work move the background images to the container of the iframe.

Comment: Thanks Its work fine but still not working on IE only working on firefox.

Answer (score -2):

Wrap your iframe with div and put it some class.
Ex:

```
<div class="wrap">
<iframe style="display:none" width="325" height="276" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</div>
```

in css:
.wrap{background:url(somepicture);}
.wrap iframe{opacity:0;}

Answer (score -4):

Try this .. it should work(tested in IE/Firefox/Google Crome)

```
<div><img src="a.JPG"></div>

<div>
<iframe style="display:none" width="325" height="276" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</div>
```